# Yii: How to work with translate Yii::t() and hyperlinks

Tags: yii

I have many lines similar to this in my code:

```
echo Yii::t('forms','Would you like to create a new item?');
```

where I want to hyperlink just around "create a new item", as an example.

Here are some alternatives that I've thought about:

1. Split the URL into 2 translated strings, surrounded by a hyperlink:

   ```
   echo Yii::t('forms','Would you like to').' <a href="/new_item">'.Yii::t('forms','create a new item').'</a>?';
   ```
2. Use placeholders, as described in the Yii documentation ( http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.i18n Although hyperlinks aren't given as an explicit example):

   ```
   echo Yii::t('forms','Would you like to {url}create a new item',array('{url}'=>"<a href='/new_item'>")).'</a>?';
   ```

There's probably an easier way to do this, but I've been unable to discover the preferred method...what's the best way to build translated strings that include URLs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link may have different placement (beginning, middle or end) and label in the translated string depending on a target language. Therefore, you should use placeholder only for url:

```
echo Yii::t(
  'forms', 
  'Would you like to <a href="{url}">create a new item</a>?', 
  array('{url}' => '/new_item')
);
```

Comment: So, will the string in my translation array just be: 'Would you like to create a new item?' In other words, will both the `<a href="">` and `</a>` just be stripped out by the Yii:t() function?

Comment: @ews2001 No, they won't be stripped. You have to include `<a href=...` part in translations as well

Comment: e.g 'Would you like to <a href="{url}">create a new item</a>?' => 'هل تريد أن <a href="{url}">تنشئ نوع جديد </a>?'. Tip: I found it very useful to learn similar translation hacks by checking yii framework core translation messages files.

Comment: @Nimir Yes, exactly. Different languages may have very different needs regarding placement and text of the link, so this is the only way to achieve great flexibility

Comment: I didn't suggest it, because you can not put `id`, `class`, `onclick` specific for one theme, in to `a` tag. I suggest you to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22379436/1407491

Comment: array('{url}' => '/new_item') must be array('url' => '/new_item')

Answer (score 8):

I suggest to you this solution:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms', 
    'Would you like to {link:create}create a new item{/link}?',
    array(
        '{link:create}'=>'<a href="/new_item">',
        '{/link}'=>'</a>',
    )
);
```

The benefit is if you want put `id`, `class`, `onclick` and more anything in `a` tag you can do it. and so the translate string in clear.
Note that `create` in `{link:create}` is just a ideal string that pointer to hyperlink string.

Another advanced sample:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms', 
    'Would you like to {link:create}create a new item{/link}? And you can {link:delete}delete the item{/link}.',
    array(
        '{link:create}'=>'<a href="/new_item" class="button">',
        '{link:delete}'=>'<a href="#" id="item-21" onclick="delete(21);">',
        '{/link}'=>'</a>',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following if you have a dynamic uri:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms',
    'Would you like to <a href=":url">create a new item?</a>',
    array(':url'=>'/new_item')
);
```

Or:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms',
    'Would you like to <a href="/new_item">create a new item?</a>',
);
```

Or if you want to pass other dynamic attributes other than the url, use the following:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms',
    'Would you like to <a :linkAttr>create a new item?</a>',
    array('linkAttr'=>'href="/new_item" id="link-id" class="link-class"')
);
```

Comment: I didn't suggest it, because you can not put `id`, `class`, `onclick` specific for one theme, in to `a` tag. I suggest you to use this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22379436/1407491

Comment: Well, if you only care about the url, you might go with my solution, but if you want to pass other attributes, a simpler way to do that than the one you mentioned is:
`echo Yii::t('forms', 'Would you like to <a :linkAttr>create a new item?</a>', array('linkAttr'=>'href="/new_item" id="link-id" class="link-class"'));`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better solution:

```
echo Yii::t(
    'forms',
    'Would you like to {action}?'
    [
        'action' => Html::a(
            Yii::t('forms', 'create a new item'),
            ['controller/action']
        )
    ]
);
```

Benefits of this solution

- You can use helpers to generate your link
- You can modify your html code without modifing the translations
- Whoever will be doing translations doesn't need to know anything about html and they can't mess the html code.

Comment: This approach also has drawbacks - splitting one phrase into two separate translations strings makes translation a lot harder.